# Windows edition requirement for Windows Server AppFabric Caching

Tags: windows, licensing, windows-server-2008, requirements, appfabric

Do i need Enterprise edition in order to install Windows Server AppFabric Caching cluster with High Availability enabled? I couldn't find any information in [the installation guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/info.aspx?na=40&p=3&SrcDisplayLang=en&SrcCategoryId=&SrcFamilyId=467e5aa5-c25b-4c80-a6d2-9f8fb0f337d2&u=http%3a%2f%2fgo.microsoft.com%2ffwlink%2f%3fLinkID%3d184618). If i do which features of Enterprise edition does it use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can only use High Availability if you're running Windows Server Enterprise Edition. There's probably a more definitive statement of this somewhere on MSDN, but I can't locate one right now, however it is mentioned on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921029.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea why? Is it kind of licensing limitation or what?